# Difference between Chabad mikvaos and other mikvaos?

Tags: halacha, chabad, mikvah-ritual-bath

I've heard from some rabbonim and educated laymen that there are some differences between Chabad mikvaos and the more standard ones. This makes it so Lubavitch women can't use any other mikva. Is there a real difference or is it a political thing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Chabad mikvaos". I assume you would include by hat designation any _mikva_ built according to the _halachos_ and _chumros_ followed by Chabad. (If not, what _do_ you mean?) If so, then isn't it obvious that Chabad women will only use Chabad mikvaos, at least _l'chat'chila_? What's the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not politics (at least not purely); it's a matter of construction. Suppose you have a big pit in the ground that collects rainwater; everyone agrees that pit is a mikvah. Fine. Today, people want a mikva with mostly clean, heated water. So they immerse in a pit of clean, heated water that is connected via a small opening to the rainwater pit. (Or usually there's an intermediate pit in between, to keep the for-dipping mikva the cleanest and warmest.) How do you connect the two pits?

*Chabad* builds *bor al gabei bor*, "pit on top of pit." If you immerse in a Chabad mikvah, you'll look down at the floor and see a small hole which leads to another pit of more-rainwater (and then another one after that). Others build them *bor al yad bor*, "pit next to pit." If you immerse in a non-Chabad mikvah, look along one of the side walls and you should see a hole leading to another pit.

So there's a legitimate halachic debate on which is the better design. Obviously ask your rabbi, but non-Chabad people would have a strong halachic preference to follow a mikvah that their *Achronim* say is the right design.

Comment: Sources would increase the value of this post.

Comment: In general both sides here exaggerate the advantages of their position and the disadvantages of the other position. Most Poskim who aren't still embroiled in severe Chasidic/Mitnagdic warfare are pretty much fine with either, at least bedieved. But yes CYLOR for personal guidance

Comment: non-Chabad people would have a strong halachic preference to follow a mikvah that their Achronim say is the right design.   Wasn't the question about the opposite situation? I know it swings both ways, but why point this one out alone?

Comment: a lot of modern mikvahs solve this by going according to both opinions and have one bor below and one on the side. Also I have never heard of someone saying they won't use one type of mikvah over another but might simply have a preference if both are available

Answer (score 4):

This [article](https://www.sefaria.org/Gray_Matter_II%2C_Building_and_Maintaining_Mikva%27ot%2C_Part_V%3B_Five_Approaches_to_Creating_a_Mikvah?lang=bi) explains the halachic pros and cons of the Chabad mikva.

Lubavitch mikva [image: Lubavitch mikva]

Common Mikva [image: Common Mikva]